# Manipulating numpy array with condition based on condition for second array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy arrays:

```
d1 = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [4, 3, 4], [4, 9, 0]])
d2 = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
```

I would like to select values in `d1` where the value of `d2` is equal to `1` and based on condition, change the selected value in `d1`.

For instance, I want to select values of `d1` where `d2` is `1`, see if they are less than `3`, and if they were less than `3`, replace them with `10`. So, the result would be:

```
np.array([[10, 2, 10], [4, 3, 4], [4, 9, 0]])
```

I know how to use loop but I am interested in indexing solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here chaining both conditions with a `bitwise AND`:

```
np.where((d1<3)&(d2==1), 10, d1)

array([[10,  2, 10],
       [ 4,  3,  4],
       [ 4,  9,  0]])
```